# Solving Intersection in 2 Ways

Tags: statistics

$X = \{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, uniformly destributed, independent from $Y$

$Y = \{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, uniformly destributed, independent from $X$

$P(X > Y \cap X = k) = $ ?

**Method 1**

$P(X > Y \cap X = k)$

$= P(X = k)P(X>Y|X=k)$

$=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{k-1}{n}$

**Method 2**

$P(X > Y \cap X = k)$

$= P(X>Y)P(X=k|X>Y)$

$= \frac{n-y}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n-y}$ ?

Comment: Method 2 seems to involve an undefined $y$ rather than the $k$ in the question

Comment: @Henry  How would I solve the question using the 2nd method such that the result would be the same? It can't be that this question can only be solved with the 1st method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 looks correct

Method 2 introduces an undefined $y$ which you should probably try to avoid, perhaps something like

$P(X > Y \cap X = k)$

$= P(X>Y)\,P(X=k\mid X>Y)$

$= \displaystyle \sum_{y=1}^n P(Y=y)\,P(X>Y\mid Y=y )\,P(X=k\mid X>Y, Y=y)$

$= \displaystyle  \sum_{y=1}^n \frac1n \cdot \frac{n-y}{n} \cdot \frac{I[k \gt y]}{n-y} $ using an indicator function

$= \displaystyle  \sum_{y=1}^{k-1}  \frac{1}{n^2} $

$=  \displaystyle \frac{k-1}{n^2}$

Comment: So for questions like these, if one way to too complicated, we should re-order the equation to see if the other way is easier?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus It will depend on the question, but calculations are often easier if you condition on random variables taking particular values